# How to get a dynamic link into a variable

Tags: javascript

I want to get this link into the variable

`var url='http://localhost:3000/documents/5b3c73fe1bde3f0788df04e4/download';`

but I don't know how to get this `5b3c73fe1bde3f0788df04e4` to change everytime I press a different document. Let's say I want somehow *notice* **:id**

`var url='http://localhost:3000/documents/:id/download';`

any idea or any tips would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
var url = '\'http://localhost:3000/documents/\' + id + \' /download\'';

    $.ajax({
    url: url
}).done(function() {
    location.href = url;
}).fail(function(xhr) {
    switch (xhr.status) {
        case 404:
            alert('404 | NOT_FOUND - Document not found!');
            break;
        case 410:
            alert('410 | GONE - Original file reference is missing or deleted!');
            break;
        case 415:
            alert('415 | UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE - Unsupported MediaType of document');
            break;
        case 500:
            alert('500 - Internal Server Error');
            break;
    }
});
```

I edited and concatenated as mentioned but it does not work in my case, which I added here.

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Are you just trying to concatenate a string? Like: `var url='http://localhost:3000/documents/' + id + ' /download'`?

Comment: is Do you have a variable named `id` ? I don't see it here.

Comment: Are you wanting to get the `id` from the url,.. you could try -> `location.pathname.split("/")[2]`

Comment: @Keith I tried that but then I get: No route matches [GET] "/undefined" and idk why.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the String you want between the slashes in the URL.

```js
var id = "thestring";
var url='http://localhost:3000/documents/'+id+'/download';
console.log(url);
```

You can also use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to add the String inside the URL.

```js
var id = "thestring";
var url=`http://localhost:3000/documents/${id}/download`;
console.log(url);
```

Comment: but this string changes if I click to another document. And why do you make an id for the string if you could explain because I don't get it sorry. Also I edited my question to let you know where I am using this.

Comment: @Gemza If you are doing AJAX, can't you just hardcode the URL for each document?

Comment: what do you mean with hardcode the URL for each document? I don't know how many documents will the user create in the future..